# Mocking wcf in silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I thought that I could create a WCF in and call it in Silverlight.  I would inject an interface to the WCF.  Then in my unit test I would mock the wcf....

However when I actually got to do this I notice that the interface does not actually have the methods that I am calling.

ie

```
myWCF.myfunctionCompleted(myhandler);
myWCF.myfunctionAsyc("test");
```

How to people typically accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a MyWCFService class which would wrap all the work calling out to my generated WCF proxies.

This helps in a few ways:

1. Gives you a single point to keep all of the code related to calling WCF (which can be quite a bit with proper error handling).
2. Gives you a class you can mock out for calling.
3. Gives you an opening to easily replace WCF if you need/want too by not avoiding WCF specific code being sprinkled everywhere (unlikely but you never know).

Comment: wow that really is disappointing.  That is a lot of code to add just to make a unit test work better.

Comment: Testing is all about creating seams within your code where you can insert fakes.  You'll see this technique quite a lot.